# Swift Autolayout warnings and other warnings i do not understand

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, warnings

The app allows users to post images/follow others etc.

So it works fine but i get the following warnings:
(I know some has to do with AutoLayout constraints but how do i know which is causing the problems?)

```
2015-07-05 17:19:37.701 Pixym[1271:72192] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: 

2015-07-05 17:19:37.702 Pixym[1271:72192] Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "HP.Pixym" 

2015-07-05 17:19:37.705 Pixym[1271:72192] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 

(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa83b822a40 H:[UIImageView:0x7fa83b8529a0(300)],
 NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa83b85ccb0 H:[UIImageView:0x7fa83b8529a0]-(10)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa83b871ff0 ),
 NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa83b8643d0 H:|-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7fa83b8529a0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa83b871ff0 ),
 NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa83b80ab00 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa83b871ff0(375)])

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa83b822a40 H:[UIImageView:0x7fa83b8529a0(300)]

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in UIKit/UIView.h may also be helpful.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a print screen of the table cell that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the constraints, it seems you have an `imageView` with a width of 300 and a left and right padding of 10. That would work fine on iPhone 5(where the screen width is 320) but it will crash on iPhone 6/ 6 Plus because there the width is bigger.

What you need to do, is figure out how would you want the image to look like on all screens. Is the 10 pixels padding more important than the width or you would like it to always have a width of 300?

If you want the width, remove the other 2 constraints and add a center horizontal in container constraint for the image.

In the other case, just remove the width constraints and all should work.

Good luck!